# When I type in git commit into the terminal I don't get sent to a text editor. What is wrong?

Tags: git, github, terminal

As I understand it, normally if you want to change the name of a comment on a commit you would simply type in git commit into the terminal and a text editor would automatically pop up.

```
The text editors might be one of the following:

GIT_EDITOR environment variable
core.editor configuration setting
VISUAL environment variable
EDITOR environment variable
```

Do I need to download one of these text editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand it, normally if you want to change the name of a
>   comment on a commit you would simply type in git commit into the
>   terminal and a text editor would automatically pop up.

Well that is true. But usually default text editor is `Vim`.

If you want to set, for example , Notepad ++.

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Of course set the location of your editor.

Comment: You got it pal.